# Android App crashes upon menu button click

Tags: android

I am testing my app on a Droid X2 and it runs 2.3.5 and when I click the menu button my app crashes. I did recently have my laptop crash when I had android studio open so maybe a file got corrupted??? Here is the debugging log.

```
03-19 21:36:03.417  22235-22235/package name here W/KeyCharacterMap﹕ Erroor loading keycharmap file '/data/usr/keychars/tegra-kbc.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.0.devname='tegra-kbc'
03-19 21:36:03.626  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-19 21:36:03.626  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'verizon/daytona/daytona:2.3.5/4.5.1A-DTN-200-18/0:user/release-keys'
03-19 21:36:03.626  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 22235, tid: 22235  >>> org.application.geysertimes <<<
03-19 21:36:03.626  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000001
03-19 21:36:03.626  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ r0 00000000  r1 00000007  r2 fffffe84  r3 00000070
03-19 21:36:03.626  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ r4 0000abe0  r5 40745308  r6 ad3836f4  r7 00000001
03-19 21:36:03.626  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ r8 0037dfe8  r9 0037e028  10 00000001  fp 421b25b0
03-19 21:36:03.626  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ ip ad384560  sp bebca398  lr ad354255  pc a8115790  cpsr 28000030
03-19 21:36:03.626  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ d0  414000003f800000  d1  3ff0000043160000
03-19 21:36:03.626  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
03-19 21:36:03.626  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ d4  bff00000bf800000  d5  0000000000000000
03-19 21:36:03.626  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ d6  0000000000000000  d7  408000003f800000
03-19 21:36:03.626  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ d8  4368000042cc0000  d9  4381800043818000
03-19 21:36:03.626  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ d10 0000000043100000  d11 0000000000000000
03-19 21:36:03.626  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
03-19 21:36:03.626  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
03-19 21:36:03.626  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ scr 60000012
03-19 21:36:04.006  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  pc 00015790  /system/lib/libutils.so
03-19 21:36:04.006  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  lr ad354255  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
03-19 21:36:04.006  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ code around pc:
03-19 21:36:04.006  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ a8115770 f4026412 ea44457f ea442405 f841221c
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ a8115780 33012023 1003f990 dbea428b bf00bd30
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ a8115790 2001f990 3002f990 f99018d1 f1113003
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ a81157a0 18d00208 47700080 47706800 b10b6803
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ a81157b0 e0012000 68886881 bf004770 33fff04f
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ code around lr:
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ ad354234 f8d24603 462071a0 465a4629 f1ba47b8
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ ad354244 d0590f00 7030f89d 980db32f ee84f7cf
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ ad354254 68204601 22c0f8d0 47904620 b9104607
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ ad354264 4478484c 6821e7b4 f8d14620 22003378
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ ad354274 47984639 b9104682 44784847 980de7a8
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ stack:
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca358  40745358
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca35c  00000000
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca360  40745358
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca364  0000cec8
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca368  40745358
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca36c  aca45da7  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca370  40745308
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca374  421b25b0
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca378  40745358
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca37c  aca45c8d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca380  0000abe0
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca384  40745308
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca388  ad3836f4
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca38c  aca45c59  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca390  df002777
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca394  e3a070ad
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00 bebca398  00000001
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca39c  00000004
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca3a0  acaa4d38
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca3a4  00000000
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca3a8  00000000
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca3ac  00000000
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca3b0  0033a888
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca3b4  407452e8
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca3b8  4000c280
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca3bc  ad3830c0
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca3c0  00000002
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca3c4  0037dfe8
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca3c8  acaa4d01
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca3cc  00000000
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca3d0  00000000
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca3d4  00000000
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca3d8  40745308
03-19 21:36:04.016  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ bebca3dc  0037dfe8
03-19 21:36:04.366  22429-22429/? I/DEBUG﹕ debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie!
03-19 21:36:04.366    1363-1363/? D/Zygote﹕ Process 22235 terminated by signal (11)
03-19 21:36:04.366   1468-19360/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process org.application.geysertimes (pid 22235) has died.
03-19 21:36:04.366    1468-1778/? I/WindowManager﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{40a074b8 org.application.geysertimes/org.app.geysertimes.MainActivity paused=false}
03-19 21:36:04.366    1468-1502/? I/BootReceiver﹕ Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_03 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
03-19 21:36:04.396    1468-1795/? W/InputManagerService﹕ Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 22235 uid 10115
```

Comment: your app wants to save the `zombie` BRAINSsss. Sorry have no idea about the issue but the `zombie` line made me laugh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the latest gradle, version 0.9.1.  See [ActionBarActivity closes after pressing hardware menu button. Without stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509850/actionbaractivity-closes-after-pressing-hardware-menu-button-without-stack-trac) for the workaround.