# Application automatically shut down without any error

Tags: android

I am creating a application for slide show. Application working good.

Some time application closed automatically.

Give below logcat  message:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000020 (code=1), thread 29357 (GC)
```

I am reading so many articles related to this message. And optimize my android code. But still give me error. after some hour application run continuously.

Is there any way to catch this type of error.

Please help me.

Comment: could you please put up whole code.

Comment: There isn't a lot of information here, but there is a signal 11 error generated by a bad png processor in the latest Android Studio.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509850/actionbaractivity-closes-after-pressing-hardware-menu-button-without-stack-trac) for more info.

Comment: @Hemantvc, Have you resolved error ? I am facing same error. Let me know for solution, if any

Comment: @HirenPatel This error occur in my case i am using multi thread operation. I forcefully clear garbage collection. Bitmap object null.