# Android development: pressing Menu button closes the application

Tags: android, android-studio

I generated new project in Android Studio using default values:

- min sdk API 8
- target sdk API 19
- compile API 19
- lang level 6.0
- theme:any Holo
- create Blank Activity

Android Studio creates for me basic "Hello World" application with 1-item menu.

Then, without touching anything, I deployed it on device (or emulator - doesn't matter) with Android GB 2.3.3 (API 10).

Everything is OK excepting the menu. 
When I'm pressing Menu button my application terminates and back to Android main screen.
There is nothing in logs.

I guess that it's connected with the themes, but I thought that on devices before Holo, 'old style' menu will appear instead of exit...

My question is how to get menu work with Android GB 2.3.3 (API 10)?

Comment: Post the exception you get in the `Logcat`.

Comment: @Luksprog: As I mentioned, there is nothing interesting: 03-21 12:25:27.411      364-364/com.example1.myapplication8.app W/KeyCharacterMap﹕ No keyboard for id 0
03-21 12:25:27.411      364-364/com.example1.myapplication8.app W/KeyCharacterMap﹕ Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin

Comment: Please refer to this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509850/

Comment: @Uchidev: it's exactly the same issue, many thanks for this reference